# breqn and \coloneq

Tags: compiling, incompatibility, mathtools, breqn

The [breqn documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/breqn.pdf) says (pg. 10)

> • The notation := must be written with the command \coloneq. Otherwise the : and the =
>   will be treated as two separate relation symbols with an “empty RHS” between them, and
>   they will be printed on separate lines.

I thus tried the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % The \coloneq they refer to comes from here, yes?
\usepackage{breqn}     % In any case, if you remove the mathtools package,
                       % LaTeX will complain that it doesn't recognize \coloneq .
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
x\coloneq 2
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

While this does not throw an error per se, it does time-out (I am using ShareLaTeX (with pdfTeX), which has a time-out limit of 1 minute I believe (unless you pay)).  Even if there were no limit and it would eventually compile correctly with no error, having to wait so long for even a MWE is sufficiently unacceptable as to be tantamount to an actual error.  On the other hand, if you replace `\coloneq` with `=`, it compiles fine in a second or less.

What could possibly be going on?  I am after all doing exactly what the documentation says to do, aren't I?

Comment: Yeah, that makes it compile, but the spacing is *not* correct inside a `dmath` environment (though it works in the usual AMS math environments as expected).

Comment: No, not at all!  I appreciate the help =)

Comment: Did you try  with `\coloneqq` (2q's) from `mathtools`?

Comment: I did.  As a matter of fact, my first guess is that it was just a typo, and so the first thing I tried was `\coloneqq`.  When that didn't work, I thought "Well, maybe it isn't a typo after all.", and then tried `\coloneq`.  When that didn't work just the same, after scratching my head for a bit, I came here.